# How do you append a value to a list by a certain frequency?

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I'm writing a program to analyse a frequency table with different functions (mean, median, mode, range, etc) and I have the user inputting their data in two lists and then converting those answers into lists of integers

```
values_input = input('First, enter or paste the VALUES, separated by spaces (not commas): ')
freq_input = input('Now enter the corresponding FREQUENCIES, separated by spaces: ')
values = values_input.split()
freq = freq_input.split()
data_list = []
```

For every value, I want the program to append it to data_input by the corresponding frequency.

For example (desired result):

If values was: 1 2 3 4
and frequency was: 2 5 7 1

I want data_list to be:
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]

At the moment I have this:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    j = 3
    while j != 0:
        data_input.append(values[i])
        j -= 1
```

But that only appends the values to data_input 3 times instead of the frequency

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input("First, enter or paste the VALUES, separated by spaces (not commas): ").split()
b = input("Now enter the corresponding FREQUENCIES, separated by spaces: ").split()
a = [int(i) for i in a]
b = [int(i) for i in b]
x = []
y = 0
for elem in a:
    temp = []
    temp.append(elem)
    x.append(temp * b[0+y])
    y += 1
final = []
for lst in x:
    for elem in lst:
        final.append(elem)
print(final)
```

I am also a newbie. I know there are more efficient ways, but for now I have come up with this.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I'm still in high school so it doesn't matter if it's not efficient or anything as long as it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list `multiplication` to create a list of each value with the appropriate frequency. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together to get the matching values for each index:

```py
values = [1,2,3,4]
freq = [2,5,7,1]

result = []
for v, f in zip(values, freq):
    result += [v] * f
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Oh wow that's so simple. Thanks so much!

Comment: @hey I've improved the answer. Should have used zip from the start...

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty much a newbie, but what's the difference between enumerate and zip? It both worked and was pretty simple...

Comment: @hey using `zip` saves doing the indexing into the `freq` list with the index from the `enumerate` by iterating both lists at the same time. So `result += [v] * freq[i]` becomes simply `result += [v] * f`